# Possible Regular Expression Question

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple program that looks up details of an IP you give it, and I will show you an example of some of my code

```
int regIndex = src.indexOf("Region:") + 16;
int endIndex = src.indexOf("<", regIndex);
String region = src.substring(regIndex, endIndex);
if(regIndex == 15) region = "None";
int counIndex = src.indexOf("Country:") + 17;
int couneIndex = src.indexOf(" <", counIndex);
String country = src.substring(counIndex, couneIndex);
```

As you can see, it is definitely not the most efficient way to do this. The website I am using gives the information like this: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/1.1.1.1

I have never really used Regular Expressions before, but it seems to me like there might be one that could really make this more efficient and easier to program, but I've been looking around and I'm pretty lost.

So basically my question is, how could I use a Regular Expression for this (Or if there is another more efficient way).

Any help would be great,
Thanks :)

Comment: Queue Standard: SO "Html is not a regular language"
Use a html parser, response.

Comment: @Oxinabox Just to clarify: Regular expressions (in lots of languages) match not only Regular Languages :) Remember, some programming languages implement some features that make theoretical regular expressions a little more powerful...

Comment: Where is the `Region:` text in the page? I can't find it...

Comment: @Oscar Mederos Region: doesn't show up on all pages, just with countries that don't have states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String s = "bla Country: Australia <bla";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Country: (.*) [<]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Country = " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Alright I am using this, however I think if I just added this for all the different details, it would have the same efficiency problem. So I want something that has the Name of the detail: detail, so this is the pattern I am attempting, however I am failing lol.   `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("</tr><th>*:*<");`

Comment: @wjans Be careful about using `.*`. It could even match `<` characters... It would be better to use `([^<]+)` instead or just make it non-greedy: `(.*?)`

Comment: Although I have never used a HTML Parser in Java (http://www.google.com/search?q=Java+HTML+Parser), I have in both Python and .NET, so I really suggest you to avoid Regular Expressions when parsing HTML...

Comment: Ok so I got this pattern to work `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<tr><th>(.*?):</th><td>(.*?)[<]");` However, it only works for the first Instance. So group(1) returns hostname, and group(2) returns "1.1.1.1", how can I make it so that it works for more than one line?

Comment: @Austin You can call `find` in a loop, it will continue to find the next match.  However, I must agree with Oscar Mederos that it should be better to use an HTML parser in this particular scenario.

Comment: @wjans Thanks, I actually just found that out right before you posted :)

Answer (score 0):

The source would look like this

```
<tr><th>Country:</th><td>Australia <img src="http://whatismyipaddress.com/images/flags/au.png" alt="au flag"> </td></tr>
```

To use regular expression means to match a pattern.

The pattern that indicates your wanted data is pretty straight forward `Country:`. You need also to match the following tags like `<\/th><td>`. The only thing is you need to escape the forward slash. Then there is the data you are looking for, I would suggest to match everything that is not a `<`, so `[^<]`, this is a capturing group with a negation at the beginning, meaning any character that is not a `<`, to repeat this add a `+` at the end, meaning at least one of the preceding character.

So, the complete thing should look like this:

```
Country:<\/th><td>\s*([^<]+)\s*<
```

I added here also the brackets, they mean put the found pattern into a variable, so your result can be found in capturing group 1. I added also `\s*`, this is a whitespace character repeated 0 or more times, this is to match whitespace before or after your data, I assume that you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are some online sites that can help you to develop a regular expression. They let you enter some text, and a regular expression and then show you the result of applying the expression to the text. This saves you having to write code as you develop the expression and expand your understanding. A good site I use alot is [FileFormat regex](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) because it allows me to test one expression against multiple test strings. A quick search also brought up [regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/), [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/). There are lots of others.

In terms of resources, the [Java Pattern class reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is useful for Java development and I quite like [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) as well.

For your problem I used fileFormat.info and came up with this regex to match "http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/1.1.1.1":

```
.*//([.\w]+)/.*/(\d+(?:.\d+){3})
```

or as a java string:

```
".*//([.\\w]+)/.*/(\\d+(?:.\\d+){3})"
```

A quick break down says anything (`.*`), followed by two slashes (`//`), followed by at least one or more decimal points or characters (`([.\w]+)`), followed by a slash, any number of characters and another slash (`/.*/`), followed by at least 1 digit (`(\d+`), followed by 3 sets of a decimal point and at least one digit (`(?:.\d+){3})`). The sets of brackets around the server name part and the IP part are called capturing groups and you can use methods on the Java Matcher class to return the contents of these sections. The `?:` on the second part of the ip address tells it that we are using the brackets to group the characters but it's not to be treated as a capturing group.

This regex is not as strict or as flexible as it should be, but it's a starting point.

All of this can be researched on the above links.